# How to call a numpy.random function when numpy is *-imported and random is non-*-imported

Tags: python, numpy

When doing scientific programming with python, I like to import numpy as

```
from numpy import *
```

because I'm using library functions all the time.

However, I'd like to be explicit in my code about which numpy submodules certain functions I'm using come from, so I import submodules 'normally', without *, e.g:

```
from numpy import *
import random
```

How should I then call random's functions?
E.g. with rand(), I can't seem to figure out how when in interpreter mode:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Jan 12 2014, 08:16:39) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from numpy import *
>>> import random
>>> random.rand(4,3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'rand'
>>> numpy.random.rand(4,3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined
```

Comment: Just for fun, try this code: `if any(x*x < 0 for x in range(3)): print 'we found a negative square!'` -- the result may surprise you out of the `from numpy import *` habit, like surprising someone with hiccups.

Comment: `import random` is overwriting the `numpy.random` module already imported as random. `from numpy import *`is really not something you should get used to doing. Both for making it explicit when using numpy functions, and for avoiding namespace collisions like this.

Comment: To reiterate, don't do `from numpy import *`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrong `random`. Use

```
from numpy import random
```

What you're importing is the built-in `random` module, not `numpy.random`.

Answer (score 2):

just call:

```
random.rand(4.3)
```

By using:

```
from numpy import *
```

you're importing every function in the numpy module into the namespace, including the random function.

check the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.random.html) on random for more info.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this

```
>>> from numpy import random
>>> random.rand(4, 3)
array([[ 0.10914871,  0.96038716,  0.63047998],
       [ 0.78165096,  0.82427611,  0.5366409 ],
       [ 0.7272912 ,  0.05932598,  0.22512217],
       [ 0.66583896,  0.6908751 ,  0.44386815]])
```

`import random` is importing the random module from Python's standard library. It does not support `rand`